# Submit Input field on page refresh

Tags: php

I'm currently using PHP to set the value of the athourised user to that of the user id and pass that into a database query. I'm also setting a refresh on the page via the JS and finally adding an input textbox to pull the value from the server and allow entry of any other user id I choose.

```
<?php
$user_name = str_replace("MY_DOMAIN\\", "", $_SERVER['AUTH_USER']);
?>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var sTargetURL = "dashboard.php";    // what this page should refresh to next

function doRedirect()
{
setTimeout("timedRedirect()", 600*1000);   // number before operator is the seconds     before refresh
}

function timedRedirect()
{
window.location.href = sTargetURL;
}

//-->
</script>

</head>
<body onload="doRedirect()">

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION = "dashboard.php">

<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="<?php echo ($user_name); ?>" NAME ="username">
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1" VALUE = "Enter">

</FORM>

<div id="right-dashboard">
<div id="titlebox-unassigned">
<h1>SRs to Close</h1>
</div>

<?php
Include 'Inc/srtoclose.php'
?>

</div>
```

The code for the DB query in the include file looks a little like this:

```
<?php

 $dbName = "C:\my.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
die("Could not find database file.");
 }

try {
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}


$sql = "SELECT SR.one, SR.two, SR.three
FROM SR
 where SR.two = 'my team' 
 and SR.three = 'Closure'
 ". $full_user_name ." 
order by SR.one";

$result = $db->query($sql);

echo "<table><tr id=\"header\"><td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><tr>";

echo "<tr><td><b>" . $row["one"] . "</b></td><td>" . $row["two"] . "</td><td>" . $row["three"]."</td>".
"</tr>
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

What I would like to do is, on the page refresh, re-submit the value in the currently in the texbox. What's happening at the moment is the page is refreshing as blank with the authorsied user name in the input box which requires the end user to click on the enter button to re-run the queries.

Is there any way to keep the session based on the current input open when the page naturally refreshes?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
window.location.href = sTargetURL;
```

Will just redirect the page, it will not submit it.

To submit the form use this instead.

```
document.getElementById("form1").submit();
```

Oh and give the form an id as well

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="dashboard.php">
```

Also you dont have to shout all your HTML tags and attributes.

Comment: Thanks for that, I still need to refresh the DB queries being pulled into the screen and it appears the input now remains static using document.getElementById("form1").submit();

Comment: Ok, what DB queries. You did not post anything DB related?

Comment: I added the code for one of the DB queries, we run several from include files on the same initial page. I'm wondering if it makes more sense to put the refresh on the include file and not the initial page.

Answer (score 0):

For submitting form with id="#someId" on page refresh using jquery, you can use following code

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload',function(){

    $("#someId").submit();

});
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/okrba54m/